# Retry for Sagemaker ModelError

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

When querying my sagemaker inference endpoint using the following code

```
config = Config(retries={"max_attempts": 4, "mode": "standard"})
sagemaker = boto3.client("sagemaker-runtime", config=config)
response = sagemaker.invoke_endpoint(
  EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,
  ContentType="application/json",
  Body=json.dumps({"s3_paths": s3_paths}),
)
```

it returns a `sagemaker.exceptions.ModelError` of type `ServiceUnavailableException` if the endpoint is too busy. Retrying would almost certainly solve the issue for me.

Unfortunately, while the error code from the endpoint is `503 - Service Unavailable`, it gets masked by the sagemaker-runtime client as a `424 - Failed Dependency` error. This status code is not included in the list of status codes triggering a retry by boto3 (see [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/retries.html#standard-retry-mode)).

Is there a way to make boto3 retry for this error or a different approach to surface the original status code `503` which would trigger a retry?

Comment: What is the error you are seeing, is there anything in the logs? What happens when retries are not enabled?